# Command line option with compound sub-options

Tags: linux, command-line, grammar

The long option style looks like this

```
--key=value
```

This syntax can easily be expanded for array-like values

```
--key=value\ 1,value\ 2,value\ 3
```

Is there a standard approach if each item takes sub-options? That is, when each value is a compound type?

One alternative is

```
--key=[object\ 1],[object\ 2],...
```

where an `object` has a syntax that is specified as a special `make_value` function. Then, querying `key` will give an array of `object`s. The syntax for specifying properties of an `object` may look like JSON or something else.

Another alternative is to give up traditional syntax completely, and force the user to type the the entire command line as a JSON object.

Comment: Not that I know of. As far as I know, your only two options are to pass the values one by one, or use a string value with data encoded e.g. a json.

Answer (score 0):

First, the standard on GNU systems is not this:

```
--key=value\ 1,value\ 2,value\ 3 // WRONG
```

But this:

```
--key=value\ 1 --key=value\ 2 --key=value\ 3
```

Which in Bash can be written this way:

```
--key=value\ {1,2,3}
```

Now, if your values are themselves key-value pairs, the typical usage for a single value is like this:

```
--key=value\ 1=42
```

Or for multiple in Bash:

```
--key=value\ {1=42,2=300,3=0}
```

Comment: **First:** My parser actually accepts the standard form as well. **Second (more important):** If `key` is a compound, then there can only be one element in the array, or there will be an ambiguity. `--key=value\ 1=42 --key=value\ 2=300` may either be interpreted as setting the properties `value 1` and `value 2` in the same object, or it may be interpreted as setting `value 1` in the first object, and `value 2` in the second.

Comment: @user877329: At this point I am unclear on specifically what you are driving at.  You should perhaps post in your question a full, complete example of one or two candidate syntaxes with explanations of what exactly they are meant to signify.